# TypeScript Type file not working

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped, tsd

I started to use TypeScript recently. Now I would like to use this [linq.js](https://linqjs.codeplex.com/) library. Even though my problem may not be specific to this library.

I installed the library with

```
jspm install npm:linq
```

I use this to import this library

```
import * as Enumerable from "linq";
```

The code works fine. But I don't get any intellisense typing.
Then I tried to install the type definition with

```
tsd install linq.3.0.3-Beta4
```

However, I still don't get correct intellisense in the code.

I found out if I remove

```
import * as Enumerable from "linq";
```

at the top of my file The intellisense typing will be WORKING, but at runtime, the library is not imported and the code won't work correctly.

I tried things like

```
/// <reference path="typings/linq/linq.d.ts" />
```

It doesn't change the situation. And I think I don't need this explicit reference since I can get intellisense without the import above.

What did I miss here?

Reference: [DefinitelyTyped  file URL](https://github.com/mihaifm/linq/blob/master/linq.js#L23). [Library file URL](https://github.com/mihaifm/linq/blob/master/linq.js#L23).

Comment: Looking at the definition file, it only seems to recognize setting up `linq` as a globally-available module. (It also, by the way, contains no actual "code" - it's just an interface file to make the IDE experience pleasant and give intellisense). The way you're bringing in LINQ (not wrong, but different) is importing it, which requires a different definition statement. Have you set up your project in tsconfig.json to use something like  "amd" or "CommonJS" or "ES6" imports? You may be able to remedy this with a small change to the definition file.